# Plesk bin site error when creating a domain from bash script

Tags: php, bash, command-line-interface, plesk

Im having an issue creating a domain on plesk, this command works fine when run through cli:

`plesk bin site --create newdomain.com -webspace-name existingdomain.com -www-root /httpdocs`

But when I add the same code above to a bash script (create_domain.sh) and try to run it with:

`sudo bash create_domain.sh`

I get the following error

`An error occurred during domain creation: hosting update is failed: cObject->update() failed: Some fields are empty or contain an improper value. ('www_root' = ')`

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This was because I was using windows to edit the bash file, I deleted it and rewrote it in  nano and it worked